# Swapping an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sorting, swap

I have an Array of 3 objects for example  [0] , [1] , [2] and after swapping my TableRows from the delegate

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSLog(@"fromIndexPath.row %d",fromIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"toIndexPath.row %d",toIndexPath.row);


    NSLog(@"%@",masterArray);

    for (id object in masterArray) {
        for(int indexValue = 0; indexValue < [self.finalContactsArr count]; indexValue++){
            if([[self.finalContactsArr objectAtIndex:indexValue] isEqual:object])
                NSLog(@"the indexValue %d", [self.finalContactsArr indexOfObject:object]);
        }
    }


    item = @"";



/////  This is working fine as below. I want to update the above loop for getting index everytime and log whole array as UI is working absolutely perfect from below code

    item = [self.finalContactsArr objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.finalContactsArr removeObject:item];
    [self.finalContactsArr insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];


}
```

I am looking for new swap order for example , if I swap 0, 1, 2  to to 1, 0 , 2 or 2, 0 , 1, so should get same index Orders "the indexValue" = 1, 0, 2. If I managed it in a seperate array so I will be getting original indexes which is stored in masterArray but the thing is for example I am swapping 2, 0 , 1 to 1, 2 ,0  "last is inserted on 1st index and others are pushed down as removeObject and insertObject logic mentioned below on UI is working" and now after completion it will start from beginning 0, 1, 2.  It should be like stack push and then after completion should be from beginning 0, 1 , 2. No need to retain anything.

Comment: NSLog(@"My Order of array elements :- %@", myarray); simply print your array after swapping operation.

Comment: want to log like 0, 1 ,2 indexes not values and I know to log object at index but want to log original indexes as 1, 0, 2

Comment: You can't do directly. You need to make copy of array and match those object with your swapping array object using isEqual method then print.

Comment: @user366584 you have to maintain a another MutableArray for tracking the changed order

Comment: You could maybe keep an index in your `item` class as an attribute.

Comment: if you need the original index of the elements, store them somewhere. if the elements of `NSArray` are `NSDictionary`, you are lucky to add a new key/value pair for the original elements with the original indexes, and that won't change after replacing elements with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer below and I also thank @Deepak Bharti for his answer too.

```
    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSLog(@"fromIndexPath.row %d",fromIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"toIndexPath.row %d",toIndexPath.row);


    if ([matchReplaceOriginalArr count] > 0)
        [matchReplaceOriginalArr removeAllObjects];

    self.matchReplaceOriginalArr = [matchReplaceArr mutableCopy];  ///// Managing this array to hold original index value in each case
    NSLog(@"matchReplaceOriginalArr %@",matchReplaceOriginalArr);


    item1 = @"";


    item1 = [self.matchReplaceArr objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.matchReplaceArr removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.matchReplaceArr insertObject:item1 atIndex:toIndexPath.row];



    for (id objectFrom_myarray in matchReplaceArr) {

        for(id objectFrom_staticMyArray in matchReplaceOriginalArr)
        {
            if([objectFrom_myarray isEqual: objectFrom_staticMyArray])
            {
                NSLog(@"the indexValue %d \t and Object is %@",[matchReplaceOriginalArr indexOfObject: objectFrom_staticMyArray],objectFrom_myarray);
            }
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"matchReplaceArr %@", matchReplaceArr);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the method [`[UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3amoveRowAtIndexPath%3atoIndexPath%3a) on the tableview object, or if there are many rows swapped, simply use [`[UITableView reloadData]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData).

Comment: I want to log the original order, for example 0, 1, 2 to 1, 0 , 2 ?? only indexes not values of array.

Comment: @user366584 Ah, when you said "log" I understood that to mean "update the new order in the table view".  Did you mean "log" as in "log to file"?

Comment: [reorderStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fromIndexPath.row]];

for (int i = 0; i < [myarray count]; i++) {
        
        if (i != fromIndexPath.row)
            [reorderStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    
    }
    
    NSLog(@"%@",reorderStr);   //This is incorrect

Comment: @user366584 I don't understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to your requirements.

**Step 1:**
Make a property as follow:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * staticMyArray;
```

**Step 2:**
Add following to `- (void)viewDidLoad` method

```
self.staticMyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.staticMyArray = [myarray copy];
```

**Step 3:**
Finally add the following at end in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath` method

```
NSLog(@"New Order of Indexes is:");
for (id objectFrom_myarray in myarray)
{
    for(id objectFrom_staticMyArray in self.staticMyArray)
    {
        if([objectFrom_myarray isEqual: objectFrom_staticMyArray])
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",[self.staticMyArray indexOfObject: objectFrom_staticMyArray]);//break;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know, if it worked or not.

Comment: But I am trying more or less the same, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify Array as per Cell-identifier. Which you have created before swapped and later.